# Stale connection in IBM MQ when connecting with WAS and Spring-JMS

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We are using Websphere Applicaion Server with Spring JMS, Around 25 applications connect to a IBM MQ. Off-late we are seeing lots of stale connection on the MQ channel to which all these applications connect.

By stale connections I mean the connection are not being used for many days and the application keeps creating new connections. We are not able to identify which application creates these connections that are not being used but they all use the same framework code

WAS version  = 8.5.5
Spring = 4.1.2

The Spring jms:listener-container has the following configuration
**connection-factory =  org.springframework.jms.connection.DelegatingConnectionFactory** 
**acknowledge=auto**
        **concurrency=2-10**
Any pointers on any configurations that can be done on QueueConnectionFactory (JMS Resource) on WAS or on the spring side would be helpful.
I know I have not given much information, but the problem is that there are no errors / exceptions, the application creates these connections to the MQ channel and all connections gets cleared when the server is restarted

Adding one more question

We use **org.springframework.jms.connection.DelegatingConnectionFactory** , for replying back, Does it make sense for us to close the session once we have send back the message?

Thanks in Advance
Charlie

Comment: What connection factory has been delegated to? Is it one from the WAS connection poolings. (have a look as well at the Spring JMS section in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html)

You can also defined ApplicationNames on connection factories in MQ - that might help track down the application that is the cause here.

Comment: The connection factory is created at the WAS with default setting for connection pool and session pool

Comment: DelegatingConnectionFactory has shouldStopConnections property. You could try that.

Comment: Is there any reason to use DelegatingCoonectionFactory? Why don't you use ConnectionFactory provided by WAS? The one provided by WAS properly caches connections and generally speaking it plays nice with Spring JmsTemplate and ListenerContainers.

Comment: DelegatingConnectionFactory has default shouldStopConnections  set as false right? . we dont want the application to start handling this

Comment: I am not sure of the rationale of using DelegatingConnectionFactory as I am he person who is debugging this issue and this is happening in our production environment , so any change like that would be difficult